# How I can operate on the current state right after updating it in the same function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Essentially I have this state object and this method:

```
const [groupData, setGroupData] = useState({});
// groupData state 
        groupData = {
           group1: [
              { id: 1, name: Mike, age: 24 },
              { id: 2, name: Bob, age: 31 }
           ],
           group2: [
              { id: 3, name: Christin, age: 21 },
              { id: 4, name: Michelle, age: 33 }
           ],
        }

const stateRef = useRef();

stateRef.current = groupData;

const handleRemovePerson = (personToRemoveById: string) => {
   
    const filteredGroupData = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(groupData).map(([key, value]) => {
        return [key, value.filter((person) => person.id !== personToRemoveById)];
      }),
    );

    setMainContentData(filteredGroupData);

    // Now check if group array does not have anymore persons, if empty then delete 
       group array

    console.log('stateRef', stateRef);
    // outputs the correct current data
    const filteredStateRef = Object.keys(stateRef).map((key) => stateRef[key]);

    console.log('filteredStateRef', filteredStateRef);
    // outputs previous data ??
};
```

I tried useRef and once I loop through it, it gives me back the previous data. How can I get the most current data after setting state and then operating on that new data right away? Thank you!

Comment: what is your `react` version?

Comment: what does the state which you set at ```setMainContentData(filteredGroupData);``` used and where is it defined?

Comment: Might be an issue with the logging of the dev tools. Try `console.log('stateRef', JSON.stringify(stateRef));` and `console.log('filteredStateRef', JSON.stringify(filteredStateRef));`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari 17.0.2

Comment: @Ben it is used to pass to a component which renders the data in the dashboard.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli those logs are producing the same results unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't access the `state` after using `setState` because it's an asynchronous operation and if you want to check something after using `setState` you need use `useEffect` hook to listen for `state` change and decide what to do with it, or in recent versions of `react` and `react-dom` you could use a not so suggested function called `flushSync` which will would update the state synchronously.

so the prefered way is to use `useEffect` like this:

```
const handleRemovePerson = (personToRemoveById: string) => {
  const filteredGroupData = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(groupData).map(([key, value]) => {
      return [key, value.filter((person) => person.id !== personToRemoveById)];
    }),
  );

  setMainContentData(filteredGroupData);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if(true/**some conditions to prevents extra stuff */){
    // do your things, for example:
    console.log('stateRef', stateRef);
    // outputs the correct current data
    const filteredStateRef = Object.keys(stateRef).map((key) => stateRef[key]);
  }
}, [mainContentData, /**or other dependencies based on your needs */])
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! A follow up question is how can I check that if one of the group[index] array is empty then return a new state with out that empty group?

Comment: @JohnMcGellan edit your question and paste the whole component and a sample of the data you want to work with, so I could see the whole picture and can help you better